# Java try-with-resource . Order of Resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

When I'm writing a simple rpc program, I encountered a strange problem! My English is poor, Please check out the code...
the code below works correctly, but when I swap the order of **A** and **B** which located in the `try-with-block` of the class `RpcImporter`,
they blocked...

1. `RpcImporter`

```
    package demo1;

    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class RpcImporter {
        public S importer(final Class serviceClass, final InetSocketAddress address) {
            return (S) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    serviceClass.getClassLoader(),
                    new Class[]{serviceClass.getInterfaces()[0]},
                    (proxy, method, args) -> {

                        try (Socket socket = new Socket(address.getHostName(), address.getPort());
                             // this is A
                             ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
                             // this is B
                             ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
                             ) {
                            System.out.println("start request");
                            output.writeUTF(serviceClass.getName());
                            output.writeUTF(method.getName());
                            output.writeObject(method.getParameterTypes());
                            output.writeObject(args);
                            return input.readObject();
                        }

                    });

        }
    }
```

2. `RpcExporter`

```
    package demo1;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

    public class RpcExporter {
        static Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        public static void exporter(int port) throws IOException {

            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                while (true) {
                    executor.execute(new ExporterTask(serverSocket.accept()));
                }
            }
        }

        private static class ExporterTask implements Runnable {
            final Socket socket;

            public ExporterTask(Socket socket) {
                this.socket = socket;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                     ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ) {
                    String interfaceName = input.readUTF();
                    Class service = Class.forName(interfaceName);
                    String methodName = input.readUTF();
                    Class[] parameterTypes = (Class[]) input.readObject();
                    Object[] arguments = (Object[]) input.readObject();
                    Method method = service.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
                    Object result = method.invoke(service.newInstance(), arguments);
                    output.writeObject(result);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. `RpcTest`

```
    package demo1;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

    public class RpcTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    RpcExporter.exporter(38088);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();

            RpcImporter importer = new RpcImporter();
            EchoService echoService = importer.importer(EchoServiceImpl.class, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 38088));
            System.out.println(echoService.echo("Are you ok ?"));
        }
    }
```

4. `EchoServiceImpl`

```
    package demo1;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

    public class RpcTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    RpcExporter.exporter(38088);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();

            RpcImporter importer = new RpcImporter();
            EchoService echoService = importer.importer(EchoServiceImpl.class, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 38088));
            System.out.println(echoService.echo("Are you ok ?"));
        }
    }
```

5. `EchoService`

   ```
   package demo1;
   ```

   public interface EchoService {
       String echo(String ping);
   }

so, why could this happen?

Comment: **I swap the order of A and B** where is `A and B` ?

Answer (score 2):

from java doc:

`ObjectInputStream`:

> ObjectInputStream Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the
>   specified InputStream.
>       A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified.
>       This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream
>       has written and flushed the header.

`ObjectOutputStream`:

> ObjectOutputStream Creates an ObjectOutputStream that writes to the specified
>   OutputStream. This constructor writes the serialization stream header
>   to the underlying stream; callers may wish to flush the stream
>   immediately to ensure that constructors for receiving
>   ObjectInputStreams will not block when reading the header.

so as you can see it says explicitly that if `ObjectOutputStream` constructor does not call first the `ObjectInputStream`constructor will be blocked

in other words, this is 2 special resources that have to call in an order(`ObjectOutputStream` constructor  first) or else `ObjectInputStream` constructor will block

(if you are using 1 Thread...)